# How to create a function that attaches the input to the end of an existing string in the function?

Tags: r, string, function

Let's say I have this function:

```
f <- function(input){
  name <- "hello_"
  }
```

I want to be able to use

`f(world)`

and have `name` be renamed to `"hello_world"`.

Important is that I don't want the input to be a string. So the solution should not involve `f("world")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `substitute` like this:

```
f <- function(input) paste0("hello_", substitute(input))
f(world)
## [1] "hello_world"
```

Note that designing your functions to use nonstandard evaluation (NSE) in this way will make them less flexible for programming.  For example, suppose we store `"world"` in `x`.  Then we get the following which is clearly not what is wanted.

```
x <- "world"
f(x)
## [1] "hello_x"
```

It is possible to get around it but it is painful:

```
do.call("f", list(x))
## [1] "hello_world"
```